# elasticsearch count number of docs matching filter

Tags: elasticsearch-5

man, this should be simple, but I can't get it.

I'm debugging, and just need to count the number of docs that match my filter.

```
GET my_index/_count
{
  "query": {
    "match_all": {},
    "filter": {
      "range": {
        "published": {
          "gte": "2018-02-19",
          "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

That's giving me

```
[match_all] malformed query, expected [END_OBJECT] but found [FIELD_NAME]"
```

I'm working with version 5.6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try this one:

```
POST my_index/_count
 {  
 "query": {
   "bool": {
      "must": [{
         "match_all": {}
      }],
      "filter": [   
         { "range": {"published": { "gte": "2018-02-19",  "format": "yyyy-MM-dd"} }}
      ]

    }
 }
}
```

You could also get the total hits when doing a simple `POST my_index/_search` **and** filter for the needed range.